# Regex to match some dates matching non-dates

Tags: regex

I'm using some Regex to find date strings of the form `Jan 12, 2015` or `Feb 3, 1999`.

The regex I'm using is `\w+\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}` and it's working correctly, but the thing is that on the file are also some strings with the form:
`Weg 58, 4047` or `Strasse 1, 4482` and I also match them.

How can I avoid those non-date matches? My approach is:

1. The first string (the one of the month, `Jan`, `Feb`, etc.) has to have always length 3.
2. The year has to start with `1`  or `2`.

The thing is that I dont know how can I add these two options to my regex. Any help please?

You can make the test right here: https://regex101.com/r/bN2pO0/1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd advise not to use regex for date validations, as you may get false positives for leap years.

Comment: Where's the problem with the leap years and regex?

Comment: Sometimes Feb 29th is valid, sometimes not.

Comment: Rephrasing... I'd advise not to use **only** regex for those validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the months won't change (ie: consistent values between January - Decemeber, we can put the 3 starting characters).

We can then use a OR `|` operator to select years starting with `1` or `2`

```
/((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{1,2},\s(1|2)\d{3})/ig
```

https://regex101.com/r/bN2pO0/3

Comment: This matches only the year, not the whole date, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You have a typo. You have `!` instead of `1`

Comment: @Borja fixed that issue. Match group 1 will be the full date.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you used `\d{1,2}` to match a digit 1 or 2 times and `\d{4}` to match a digit 4 times, you can use `\w{3}` to match a word character 3 times.

For the year, you can use the pipe "or" operator `|`.

```
\w{3}\s\d{1,2},\s(?:1|2)\d{3}
```

Although, this will also match non-dates of form Abc xy, 1xyz

If you want, you can go with brute force approach or just get rid of regex and use code to capture the dates.

Brute force:

```
(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s[0-2]?[0-9],\s[12]\d{3}
```